Trace norm and operator norm the largest and smallest unitarily invariant norms?
A unitarily invariant norm $\|\ \|_i$ is a norm on operators on a Hilbert space satisfying $\|A\|_i=\|UAV\|_i$, where $U,V$ are unitary and $A$ is any operator. Impose the normalization that $\|P\|_i=1$, where $P$ is the projector onto an arbitrary 1-dimensional subspace (the subspace doesn't matter by unitary invariance). Then it is known (see Bhatia, Matrix Analysis pg. 93) that in the finite-dimensional setting, $$\|A\|_\infty\le \|A\|_i \le \|A\|_1,\hspace{5em}(1)$$ where $\|\ \|_\infty$ is the operator norm, which is also the Schatten $\infty$-norm, and $\|\ \|_1$ is the trace norm, which is also the Schatten 1-norm (recall that this is the sum of the singular values). In other words, all unitarily invariant norms are bounded between the two extreme Schatten norms.
I am conjecturing that this result holds for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space as well. More precisely, suppose $\|\ \|_i$ is a norm defined on a subspace $S$ of the (possibly unbounded) linear operators on a Hilbert space. We call this norm unitarily invariant if $\|A\|_i=\|UAV\|_i$, where $U,V$ are unitary and $A$ is any operator in $S$; this implicitly assumes the range is unitarily invariant, $S=USV$. We assume $S$ contains the 1-dimensional projectors $P$ so that we may still enforce the normalization $\|P\|_i=1$. Again, we have the unitarily invariant Schatten norms $\|\ \|_\infty$ and $\|\ \|_1$, defined on the spaces of bounded linear operators and trace class operators, respectively.
Question: does (1) remains true, where we only demand each inequality to hold when both quantities being compared are defined?

Does your $S$ still contain all rank one projections so that you can normalize with $|P| = 1$?

Yes, we definitely should still assume that! Thanks
